# How to configure A type record Or IP address to static website in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, godaddy-api, azure-static-website-hosting

I created a html page and placed in Azure blob storage.

After I created an endpoint and configured it in GoDaddy DNS as a CNAME.

But what value do i need to configure for A value in GoDaddy.

I created a CNAME record with DNS provider.

I used example names in below. But the behavior is same with actual names.

[image]

in Azure getting error

[image]

Comment: Based on the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-custom-domain it seems like you don't need the A record.

Comment: Yes, but i couldn't connect to my custom site.

Comment: have you tried this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-temporary-cdnverify-subdomain it is an example with GoDaddy

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever solve this? I think I might have to use a the subdomain `www`. You get an IP with an Azure web app, but I don't think you get one with a storage account.

Comment: My domain registrar allows easy forwarding, so I just made `mydomain.com` forward to `www.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 2):

**If your host is Azure:**

1 - GO to DNS management in GoDaddy

2 - Set up forwarding by adding the www. site like this:
[image]

3 - Wait 24h and then try to access the website without www

**If your host is not azure (and unlike Azure provides you an IP Address):**

1 - GO to DNS management in GoDaddy

2 - Add an A record with the following configuration:

- Type: A
- Name: @
- Value: YOUR_WEBSITE_IP_ADDRESS
- TTL: 1 hour

3 - Keep your CNAME record as well, which must be:

- Type: A
- Name: www
- Value: YOUR_AZURE_STATIC_WEBSITE_URL
- TTL: 1 hour

4 - Wait 24h and then try to access the website without www

Comment: For Azure CDN site with https, does GoDaddy forwarding work? or any alternative solutuions?

Comment: @Shawn I believe that might be possible but I've never tried with HTTPS. Sorry!